# Assign links to an image and make them clickable, using only Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, magento

I have an image slider that is linked with some links, in the desktop version when you click on the image it is directed to the link correctly, but when I switch to the mobile version and click on the image the link does not work, I tried to resolve this issue using this Jquery:

```
jQuery (document) .ready (function () {
jQuery ('. fullwidthbanner-container ul> li: nth-child (3) img'). each (function () {
var currentImage = jQuery (this);
currentImage.wrap ("<a target='_self' href='http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com'" + currentImage.attr("href") + "'</a>");
});
});
```

but it still didn't work, is there a way for me to make these images hyperlinked?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide html along with this js. targeting from hierarchy is *very* dangerous, and I'd recommend nearly *any* alternative aside from it. Is there no way for you to add a class name or attribute to the links? There may be a better way to make the links work on mobile as well aside from a hacky JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Would advise trying something like the following.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.fullwidthbanner-container > ul > li:eq(3) > img').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).wrap(function() {
      return "<a href='http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com" + $(this).attr("src") + "'></a>";
    });
  });
});
```

See More: https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Images usually have a `src` attribute and not a `href`.